# Accessing typeDefs in the dist folder | NestJS/GraphQL

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, nestjs

**Context:** I had a project at which backend was written with GraphQL/lambdas. Now I want to convert whole project to NestJS/GraphQL.

I have joined.graphql file in src/GraphQL folder and there is an import (usage) of this file in another .ts file. When I try to start the project with nest start command, none of *.graphql files are copied to dist folder. Then, that import throws an error as there is no joined.graphql file in the dist folder.

I tried to add nest-cli.json file with assets field to include ./**/*.graphql files as assets. Now the issue is indeed fixed. But...

**Problem:**
Another error occured as

```
/<MY_PROJECT>/dist/src/GraphQL/joined.graphql
type Query {
     ^^^^^

SyntacError: Unexpected identifier
```

The code was trying to import `typeDefs`. I think there should be something a bit tricky since I'm not starting the project with nest but trying to convert to nest. Maybe missing some steps to work correctly with graphql. I'm not sure.